# Ajax not loading the updated content, even tho i disabled caching

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I hosted my website on google drive. Since it doesn't support PHP, i use Ajax instead. I keep the header and the footer on the index.html page, and for the body part: i load the relevant page using Ajax. However, when i modify a certain page on google drive, ajax is not loading the modified page, it loads the old page.

That is my website.
http://diablosoft.hopto.org/

This is my Ajax function.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
function goTo(page){
    var loadingEle = document.getElementById("loading");
    loadingEle.style.display = "block";
    var pgContainer = document.getElementById("pageContainer");
    pgContainer.innerHTML = "";
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
     $.ajax({
        url: "pages/"+page+".html",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {
            setTimeout(function() {
            pgContainer.innerHTML = "";
            $("#pageContainer").html(data);
            loadingEle.style.display = "none";
            }, 300);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

And this is my updated content. The following is the prices of my products(Hacks page), here is how they look in HTML.

```html
<h6 class="txt">$7.99</h6>
<h6 class="txt">$14.99</h6>
```

And here's what i see... ctrl + f5 also doesnt work. That only works for the index page, but not for the body pages loaded via Ajax.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJT2t.jpg)

Comment: why dont u use a free host? Google Drive is not intended for hosting

Comment: Nvm, i cancelled my online service. I use Google Drive for it provides me with FREE SSL. But the site load is slow from time to time, and some times it doesn't even load.

Comment: you can get a free ssl in https://letsencrypt.org/